# Impossible to pass a parameter to a react wrapper

Tags: reactjs

I use RBNB calendar
http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?selectedKind=DayPickerSingleDateController&selectedStory=single%20month&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=kadirahq%2Fstorybook-addon-actions%2Factions-panel

I want to pass a parameter (_onDateChange)

```
<DayPickerSingleDateControllerWrapper  _onDateChange={this.handleDateChange} />
```

, but impossible, I have this error :

> Warning: Failed prop type: DayPickerSingleDateController: unknown
>   props found: _onDateChange warning.js:33
>       in DayPickerSingleDateController (at DayPickerSingleDateControllerWrapper.js:138)
>       in DayPickerSingleDateControllerWrapper (at DmcMeetingForm.js:334)
>       in div (at DmcMeetingForm.js:331)
>       in div (at DmcMeetingForm.js:330)
>       in div (at DmcMeetingForm.js:363)

So I do not know which security o code has been made to make this hard, but I need to communicate between component... Thank you

Comment: did you try it like this: `onDateChange={this.handleDateChange}` (no underscore)?

Comment: TKS it works... so _ does issues at some point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onDateChange={this.handleDateChange} (no underscore)